# Combining lists as rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and i was wondering if there is a way to create a dataframe through lists. Here is an example.

```
n = c(1,4,5)
b = c(7,19,20)
v = c(3,8,9,4,5)
x = list(n,b,v)
```

If i use the command x i get columns. Is there i can combine them as rows if they have similar headers(like employee, count,id, row number, pages, page visits) and create a dataframe like this?

```
employee | count | id  |row number| pages| page visits

1          4       5    
7          19      20
3           8       9       4       5
```

Comment: With `x` you get vectors, not columns.

Comment: I have a list with column headers(30) and only one observation for one list, in some cases (20) and hence i get the columns. You are right about the vector.

Comment: So are you saying that you have a `list` of `data.frame`s, but with different numbers of columns? Please edit your question to include (small) sample data that actually represents the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `stri_list2matrix` from the "stringi" package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(x, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "1"  "4"  "5"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "7"  "19" "20" NA   NA  
# [3,] "3"  "8"  "9"  "4"  "5"
```

However, your sample data only has 5 columns and you are expecting to create a `data.frame` with 6 columns.

---

You can also try `listCol_w` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_w(data.table(id = seq_along(x), x), "x", fill = NA_real_)
   id x_fl_1 x_fl_2 x_fl_3 x_fl_4 x_fl_5
1:  1      1      4      5     NA     NA
2:  2      7     19     20     NA     NA
3:  3      3      8      9      4      5
```

The `NA_real_` is so that the results can be retained as numeric. (`NA_integer_` is also appropriate here.)

Comment: My lists are actually not vectors. They have data of one observation like employee, count,id, row number,pages, page visits. Any suggestions how i can append them(with missing column values for few lists)?

Answer (score 0):

```
require(plyr)
Reduce(function(z,y) rbind.fill(z,
                setNames( data.frame(as.list(y)), cnams[1:length(y )])),
      x, 
      init=setNames(data.frame(as.list(cnams))[0,], cnams) )

  employee count id row_number pages page_visits
1        1     4  5       <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
2        7    19 20       <NA>  <NA>        <NA>
3        3     8  9          4     5        <NA>
```